# properly declare local function angular2 + typescript

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I am converting angular 1 to angular 2 (ionic 2), I created this provider to replace a service, but I get errors with the local functions.

**How to declare a local function using angular2 and Typescript?**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class PouchSeed {

    constructor() { }

    function normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
        function normalize(doc) {
            doc = angular.copy(doc);
            Object.keys(doc).forEach(function (prop) {
                var type = typeof doc[prop];
                if (type === 'object') {
                    doc[prop] = normalize(doc[prop]);
                } else if (type === 'function') {
                    doc[prop] = doc[prop].toString();
                }
            });
            return doc;
        }

        var output = normalize(doc);
        output._id = id || doc._id;
        output._rev = doc._rev;
        return output;
    }
    ....
    seed(db, designDocs, callback) {
        if (!db || !designDocs) {
            throw new TypeError('`db` and `design` are required');
        }

        var local = objMapValues(objMapKeys(designDocs, addDesign), normalizeDoc);

        var seedPromise = db.allDocs({include_docs: true, keys: Object.keys(local)})

                .then(function (docs) {

                    var remote = {};

                    docs.rows.forEach(function (doc) {
                        if (doc.doc) {
                            remote[doc.key] = doc.doc;
                        }
                    });

                    var update = Object.keys(local).filter(function (key) {
                        if (!remote[key])
                            return true;
                        local[key]._rev = remote[key]._rev;
                        return !docEqual(local[key], remote[key]);
                    }).map(function (key) {
                        return local[key];
                    });

                    if (update.length > 0) {
                        return db.bulkDocs({docs: update});
                    } else {
                        return Promise.resolve(false);
                    }
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback(null, result);
                    }
                    return Promise.resolve(result);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback(err, null);
                    }
                    console.log(err);
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                });

        return seedPromise;

    };



}
```

Errors:

```ts
Typescript Error
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/providers/pouch-seed.ts
    function normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
        function normalize(doc) {
```

Comment: You can't put a *"local function"* inside a class in TypeScript. As the error says, you can only put constructors, methods, accessors or properties in a class. See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: If `seed` and `normalizeDoc` are on the same level, why don't you remove function from `normalizeDoc`?

Comment: I am new to angular2, I don't understand classes yet!
@echonax indeed, they are on the same level I guess, so I removed the occurrences of "function", and now I have another error 
`Typescript Error
';' expected.
src/providers/pouch-seed.ts
normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
 normalize(doc) { `

Comment: Is it ok to nest methods like this? Should I add ";" somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

From how you are using that `normalizeDoc` method, there's no need for it to be a nested function. So, you can change your class to:

```
@Injectable()
export class PouchSeed {

    constructor() { }

    normalizeDoc(doc, id) {

        var output = this.normalize(doc);   // <-- note how you call your normalize method
        output._id = id || doc._id;
        output._rev = doc._rev;
        return output;
    }

    normalize(doc) {
      doc = angular.copy(doc);
      Object.keys(doc).forEach(function (prop) {
        var type = typeof doc[prop];
        if (type === 'object') {
          doc[prop] = normalize(doc[prop]);
        } else if (type === 'function') {
          doc[prop] = doc[prop].toString();
        }
      });
      return doc;
    }
    ....

}
```